# On the meromorphic continuation of a multiple Dirichlet series

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
D(s,z)=\sum_{c\geq 1}\frac{1}{c^s}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^z}e\left(\frac{n}{c}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
be the multiple Dirichlet series defined for $\Re(s)>1$ and $\Re(z)>1$.

On the one hand, by writing $n=n_1c+\ell$ with $n_1\geq 0$ and $1\leq \ell\leq c$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
D(s,z)=\sum_{c\geq 1}\frac{1}{c^{z+s}}\sum_{1\leq \ell\leq c}e\left(\frac{\ell}{c}\right)\zeta\left(z,\frac{\ell}{c}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\zeta(z,\beta)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+\beta)^z}$ is the Hurwitz zeta function. Thus $D(s)$ has analytic continuation to $\Re(s+z)>2$.

On the other hand, by the Hurwitz equation, for $\Re(z)<0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\zeta(z,\beta)=\frac{\Gamma(1-z)}{(2\pi)^{1-z}}
\sum_{\epsilon\in\{\pm 1\}}
e\left(\epsilon\frac{1-z}{4}\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e(-\epsilon n\beta )}{n^{1-z}},
\end{eqnarray*}
we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
D(s,z)&=&\frac{\Gamma(1-z)}{(2\pi)^{1-z}}
e\left(\frac{1-z}{4}\right)
\sum_{c\geq 1}\frac{1}{c^{s+z-1}}\\
&&+
\frac{\Gamma(1-z)}{(2\pi)^{1-z}}
e\left(\frac{1-z}{4}\right)\sum_{n> 1}\frac{1}{n^{1-z}}
\sum_{c\mid (n-1)}c^{1-s-z}\\
&&+\frac{\Gamma(1-z)}{(2\pi)^{1-z}}
e\left(-\frac{1-z}{4}\right)\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{1-z}}
\sum_{c\mid (n+ 1)}c^{1-s-z}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It gives an expression of $D(z,s)$ for $\Re(z)<0$ and $\Re(s)>1$.

Is there an expression of such Dirichlet series at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\Re(s)<0$? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think your last display provides meromorphic continuation for $\Re(z)<0$ and $\Re(s)>1$. This is not what you say in the line below the last display.

Comment: Thanks! you are right. @GHfromMO